# rc.local vs upstart vs systemd

Tags: security, startup

We are developing a product that depends on a start-up script. Our prototype utilizes rc.local for this purpose, but we've noticed that upstart and systemd are more modern approaches. However, we haven't discovered much concrete evidence for why to prefer upstart or systemd over rc.local.

Why to prefer upstart or systemd? We are particularly concerned with security in terms of deciding on a method.

Comment: "concerned with security" what does this mean? What threats do you fear, and how will they be affected by how you start your "product"?

Comment: This is our first Linux project, coming from Windows environment. So just want to ensure we aren't doing anything inherently insecure or taking an inappropriate method for starting services.

Comment: Note to moderators: 1) google brought this up first for me, 2) the given answer was fact based and helpful. Please refrain from over-moderation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off, your product shouldn't use `rc.local` *at all*. `rc.local` is for the system administrator to fiddle with; they can do whatever they want with it (as long as it exits successfully). This makes editing it tricky at best.

Now which should you use? The answer is simple.

#### All of them.

A system uses a single init system at any given time. If you provide configuration for all of them, the one which is most compatible with the running one is used automatically.

## A quick overview

### System V init

- Both Upstart and systemd support these, so you can write sysv init scripts and have them work everywhere.
- This init system only does one thing: call your script with an appropriate parameter. Everything else - tracking the started processes, changing users, setting the environment, etc., has to be done in your script. This makes the init script method fragile if you're not good at scripting (scripts are typically shell scripts, but I suppose it can be something else). Some standard functions are provided for convenience, locations varying from distro to distro.
- Ordering of init scripts is done based on filenames and presence in the various `/etc/rc*` directories, and on [special comment headers](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

### Upstart (≤ 14.04)

- Event-based. Makes it possible to have your job wait for particular event to happen (filesystems mounted, network up) before starting.
- Unfortunately, Upstart's implementation makes it tricky to use more complex startup configuration. Also, it's difficult to insert your job in the dependency chain of some other job after the fact.

### systemd (≥ 16.04)

- Dependency-based. Units are started when needed. See [Systemd for Upstart users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) for more info. Current default init in Debian, Ubuntu and RHEL-based systems.
- Systemd's cgroups-based approach for tracking processes is the most reliable. This makes it difficult for processes to escape a given (security) context or resource limitation.
- Administrators can easily override init configuration without stepping on the toes of the package maintainer.

Both Upstart and systemd have clear advantages over sysv init. Both of them are more declarative than imperative, with builtin support for various tasks involved in managing services. You should use the most modern init system available in whichever releases you support.

Answer (score 2):

Systemd is an advancement on Upstart so asking which is better or secure in my opinion doesn't really do justice. Better to ask yourself "*do I want to do things the old way*" if so Upstart, else Systemd.

Check the differences [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), personally I like to move forward as that's the intention of Systemd. Both have excellent security and since your coming from Windows please read up on the *history of Linux Security*, then I believe you will decide better.

Again `rc.local` is old school welcome to Linux, we believe in the future so get things done in the now rather than in the past.

Comment: Consider adding a simple discriminator early in the answer: Upstart is default in 14.04, and has since been demoted from main to universe in 17.10. systemd is default in 16.04 and newer.